# Mount Permission Denied on Cloned System

Tags: linux, permissions, redhat, mount

We have cloned a RHEL (system1) to a new server (cloned_sys). I've added cloned_sys credentials to Data Domain, but whenever I try to mount the NFS, I get a permissions error. If I go in and add system1 to the DD, I am able to mount FROM the cloned_sys. What is cloned_sys hanging on to from the original system that I need to update?

Any ideas? Appreciate the help.

Comment: your question without providing details is very vague. have you changed everything i.e. network/hostname/IP/etc in your cloned_sys? it is really hard to say anything without providing specific data here. also pls post here the export file for both systems

Comment: please clarify what is your data domain, anyway if your data domain is = filer use showmount -e filername | grep hostname_of_your_new_server.

Comment: This is for a client's domain, which is why I was being a bit vague / didn't post any transcripts. 

The RHEL box was cloned from a physical to a virtual box. Using showmount -e filename shows me the hostname of the correct server. If I ping the servers, everything show's correctly. However, if I attempt to mount from the cloned server, it tells me I don't have permissions. If we add the original server to the Data Domain permissions, I am able to mount from the cloned server. We are doing that for a work around, we were just looking in to WHAT was causing the issue. I'm not a RHEL guy.

Comment: We have 3 locations: NJ, NY and NC.Each has it's own Data Domain. We don't want NJ to be able to access NY or NC, NY to access NJ or NC, etc. Currently NY was cloned to NC. I'm unable to mount the NC DD to the NC Server without supplying the NY server name in the NC DD.

Comment: @ostendali yes, the network, hostname, IP, MAC address, etc. was changed. However, it's still hanging on to something from the original server that isn't allowing me to mount.